# Excel picture tools format vba

Tags: excel, vba, effects, image

In excel & word 2007 there is a picture tools tab that shows up in the ribbon when you insert a picture or clip art and there is the smart art. Is there a way to manipulate these objects and settings (e.g. transparency, position, effects etc) in vba. A macro doesn't seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I don't believe there is a way to manipulate with code these picture aspects in office 2007. 
If anyone out there has a better answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I know that in Excel VBA (my experience is prior than 2007), you could manipulate many aspects of images via the `Shape` object.  A good way to explore the `Shape` object is to record a macro while you try to manipulate the image and then look at the VBA code it created to see what you did.  This doesn't always work perfectly, but it's a great way to start.

Also, you might be interested in checking out [the answer I gave to a related question about moving images between cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905060/moving-images-between-cells-in-vba/1907833#1907833) .

I'm not sure how many aspects of an image you can manipulate just with the `Shape` object, but it's worth taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

This will help if you want to change the actual picture displayed.  It's non-VAB stuff, but the technique is worth knowing about

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489836/how-to-show-a-picture-in-a-cell-depending-on-the-value-of-another-cell/28489837#28489837)